# Replace NA value in column with modified date in other column

Tags: r, date, if-statement, replace, na

I have the following dataset:

```
  A          B
2007-11-22 2004-11-18
      <NA> 2004-11-10
```

when the value of column A is NA, I want this value to be replaced by the date in B, except with an additional 25 days added.
Here is what the outcome should look like:

```
   A          B
2007-11-22 2004-11-18
2004-12-05 2004-11-10
```

So far, I have tried the following if else formula, but with no success.

```
library(lubridate)
data$A<- ifelse(is.na(data$A),data$B+days(25),data$A)
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it or give me an alternate solution? The code to build my dataset is below.

```
A<-c("2007-11-22 01:00:00", NA)
B<-c("2004-11-18","2004-11-10")
data<-data.frame(A,B)
data$A<-as.Date(data$A);data$B<-as.Date(data$B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the issue can be traced back from the source code of `ifelse`. When you type `View(ifelse)`, you will see some lines in the bottom of the source code as below

```
    ans <- test
    len <- length(ans)
    ypos <- which(test)
    npos <- which(!test)
    if (length(ypos) > 0L)
        ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]
    if (length(npos) > 0L)
        ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos]
    ans
```

where `test` is logic array, and `ans` is initialized as a copy of `test`. When running `ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]`, the class of `ans` is coerced to `numeric`, rather than `Date`. That's why you have integers on `A` column after using `ifelse`.

---

You can try the code below

```
data$A <- as.Date(ifelse(is.na(data$A), data$B + days(25), data$A), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

which gives

```
> data
           A          B
1 2007-11-22 2004-11-18
2 2004-12-05 2004-11-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data given reproducibly in the Note at the end -- in particular we assume both columns are of `Date` class -- compute a logical vector `is_na` which indicates which entries are NA and then set those from B.

```
is_na <- is.na(data$A)
data$A[is_na] <- data$B[is_na] + 25
```

This would also work and has the advantage that it does not overwrite `data`:

```
transform(data, A = replace(A, is.na(A), B[is.na(A)] + 25))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
         A          B
2007-11-22 2004-11-18
        NA 2004-11-10"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
data[] <- lapply(data, as.Date)  # convert to Date class
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ifelse` you could use `coalesce`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

A <- c("2007-11-22 01:00:00", NA)
B <- c("2004-11-18","2004-11-10")
data <-data.frame(A,B)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(A = as_date(A),
         B = as_date(B),
         A = coalesce(A,B+days(25)))
```